# Android bluetooth Enabling going crazy

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Android Bluetooth enabling is going crazy. I am working on a chat type app which will populate the bluetooth devices (paired non-paired and discovered in range) into a  `ListView`.

as soon as I switch on the bluetooth, the background code

```
ArrayOfDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
if(ArrayOfDevices.size()>0)//paired dev more than 0
{
    for(BluetoothDevice device: ArrayOfDevices)
{
    listAdapter.add(device.getName()+ "\n" +device.getAddress());
}
//for breadcast recievers and registering them//
}
```

this listadapter is filled properly, but it needs bluetooth already switched on for this matter. 
bluetooth code is:

```
        if(!btAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enablingggggg the bluetooth device", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent iBlueEnabled = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(iBlueEnabled, 1);
}
else // 


//some code follows
```

The problem is that enabling the bluetooth is simple but problem arises when I have the code to follow after enabling the bluetooth. that code gets executed before the bluetooth is enabled properly (as it takes time).
question of using a custom bluetooth adapter is out of reach for me. 
Any solution from experts??? 
thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to execute your code only if the Bluetooth is enabled successfully.

override `onActivityResult()` and if you get `RESULT_OK` then execute your code to make sure that the adapter is already enabled.

**Edit**

Using `Semaphore` is another alternative, here is a quick example

```
final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0, true);
```

Before running the code that using the Bluetooth adapter if is not enabled

```
semaphore.acquire();
```

After the Bluetooth adapter is enabled or failed i.e. in onActivityResult

```
semaphore.release();
```

Comment: no, its not working. the onStart() is simultaneously running the code with the onActivityResult(). problem persists. anyway, thankyou for the reply :)

Comment: Alternative solution is to use `Semaphore` to make sure that the other does not work before the Bluetooth is enabled

Comment: better I should find alternative as `semaphores` were the nightmare topic i skipped in my operating system course.

Comment: I added a quick example on how to use semaphore. The idea is that you define a semaphore with no permits i.e. 0

Then the method `semaphore.acquire()` will block until the method `semaphore.release()` is called